# AngularJs sending form data to email in SPA

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to build a contact form for SPA. I am using AngularJS to send data to email without page refresh. I am jcs-autoValidate to validate form field. I am using Bootstrap form for front-end and PHP for server side.

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['jcs-autoValidate']);

app.run(['defaultErrorMessageResolver',
        function(defaultErrorMessageResolver) {
            defaultErrorMessageResolver.getErrorMessages().then(function (errorMessages) {
                errorMessages['validPhone'] = 'Please enter valid phone number';
            });
        }]);

app.controller('FormController', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.result = 'hidden'
   $scope.resultMessage;
   $scope.formData;
   $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
   $scope.submitted = false;
   $scope.submit = function(help) {
       $scope.submitted = true;
       $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
       if (help.$valid) {
           $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: 'process.php',
               data: $.param($scope.formData),
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
           }).success(function(data){
               console.log(data);
               if (data.sucess) {
                   $scope.submitButtonDisabled = true;
                   $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                   $scope.result = 'bg-sucess';
               } else {
                   $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
                   $scope.resultMessage = data.message;
                   $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
               }
           });
       } else {
           $scope.submitButtonDisabled = false;
           $scope.resultMessage = 'Failed, your message was not deliver. Please try sending again or reach us on the above numbers. Thank you!';
           $scope.result = 'bg-danger';
       }
   }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['phone']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please the form completely.');
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From = $_POST['email'];
    $mail->FromName = $_POST['name'];
    $mail->AddAddress('someemail@someone.com');
    $mail->Body = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\nMessage: " . stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    if (isset($_POST['ref'])) {
        $mail->Body .= "\r\n\r\nRef: " . $_POST['ref'];
    }
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit;
    }

    $data = array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Thank you for contacting us! We will get back to you soon.');
    echo json_encode($data);

    } else {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Please the form completely.');
    echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

Console

> {"success":true,"message":"Thank you for contacting us! We will get
>   back to you soon."}

However, I am not getting any email on my email address, I have changed email address above in the code for demo purpose. If someone can guide me or point as what am I doing wrong, because I have changed my code 10 times without success.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: not an expert in php but I can't understand why you need the second if statement in your `php`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything to do with angular at all ... test the php mail all by itself without any ajax involved. That seems to be your problem

Comment: I am sorry but which second "if" are you talking about...

Comment: I didn't get it... test the php mail all by itself... could you be please more elaborate the problem

Comment: also try setting `$mail->to` and check your spam box

Comment: Is anything getting logged to the console with your success statement: `console.log(data)`?

Comment: How to stupid of me I just checked my spam folder without making any changes and I see the emails... however, the form doesn't get clear and I don't get any success messages... any idea? and thank you for spam folder idea!

http://newangularform.comlu.com/